# Not being able to access local JS file from local HTML in react-native-webview iOS platform

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-webview

I need to access local JS file from a local HTML file from react-native-webview in react-native app on iOS platform.

I have a js file and a html file. I am willing to access the JS file with script tag from the local HTML file.

I am able to access the HTML file but not the JS file from HTML file. Both the files are kept in local folder under src.

I have a *test.html* file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <div>
        <button id="testButton" onclick="abc()">Test</button>
        <input type="text" id="testText" value="hi"></text>


        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

I have another *test.js* file as:

```
function abc(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML="<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>";
    document.getElementById("testText").value = "Arthita Chatterjee";
}
```

I am trying to access from *react-native-webview* in the following way:

```
const ioshtmlsource=require('../../www/test.html');

<WebView
        
 originWhitelist={['*']}
 source={ioshtmlsource}
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 domStorageEnabled={true}
 allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
 allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
 allowFileAccess={true}
 automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
 onMessage={event => console.log(JSON.stringify(event.nativeEvent.data))}/>
```

Note: both the html and js files are present in www folder and html is being shown. Hence the relative path is correct here I think.

This is what I am getting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zsmv.png

Error I got:

> Error: 'src/www/test.js' cannot be loaded as its extension is not registered in assetExts

To solve this, I have already added asset extension in metro.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 
  resolver: {
    assetExts: ['js', 'png']
  }
};
```

Still, got this error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not a function
>
> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tried in another way by adding the files in IOS folder and added the same files in xcode project by opening the .xcproj file in xcode and including the HTML and JS file in the xcode project.

Still clicking on the HTML button, no action is being performed which indicates it is not getting JS file.